# WSL2 is running in Windows 11 but won't launch and it is not accessible via SSH

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, openssh, wsl2

My WSL in my Win 11 has been running smoothly until I suddenly cannot longer access it by any means (Ubuntu app, WSL from CMD/Powershell, and even SSH).

My Win 11 always shows that WSL2 is running but there is no way to communicate with it.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> wsl -l -v
  NAME            STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-22.04    Running         2
```

When trying to access WSL2, it just hangs up, and it terminates. However, it looks like wsl is still running.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> wsl ~
The Windows Subsystem for Linux instance has terminated.
PS C:\Windows\system32> wsl -l -v
  NAME            STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-22.04    Running         2
PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

Since I have openssh running in WSL, and I have accessed it without issues before, I tried that, but again, no response from WSL and I get some errors as below (IPs are redacted):

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> ssh -v rls@<IP>
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.4.3
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to <IP> [<IP>] port 22.
debug1: connect to address <IP> port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host <IP> port 22: Connection timed out
```

Additional verbosity in ssh shows this line:

> debug3: finish_connect - ERROR: async io completed with error: 10060, io:0000015A0C28BD30

I'd like to avoid restarting WSL at this point because I had a mdadm service in WSL that is managing my RAID and it was backing up some data before this issue happened. Any help on how to troubleshoot this would be appreciated.

Comment: *"mdadm service in WSL that is managing my RAID"* - At some point, I'd be curious about that.  It sounds a bit risky to me.  I like WSL2 a *lot*, but I'm not sure I'd trust it with something at that level.

Comment: It has been working well so far. I just needed to also start a nohup bash function to make sure the WSL instance was running in the background of Win at all times.

Answer (score 0):

> `The Windows Subsystem for Linux instance has terminated.`
>
> I'd like to avoid restarting WSL at this point because I had a mdadm service in WSL that is managing my RAID and it was backing up some data before this issue happened.

Unfortunately, it's most likely that your `mdadm` service is already dead as well, but *just in case* it's a shell issue, try something like:

```
wsl -d ls /
```

and/or

```
wsl cat /etc/os-release
```

If those work, then move on to something like:

```
wsl ps axj
```

to see if you can spot any problems there.

Also, if it *is* a shell issue that is preventing you from accessing the instance:

```
wsl ~ -e bash --noprofile --norc
```

... will attempt to start Bash without loading any configuration/startup.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I tried all the commands you suggested but none of them worked. WSL hangs for a while and then I get `The Windows Subsystem for Linux instance has terminated.` The only thing that seems to work is `wsl -l -v`, which shows WSL as running... go figure.

Comment: @ricardo3889 Sorry to hear!  Like I said, I didn't have much hope for it, but worth a shot. :-/